# Scaling of image (scriptable image processing system)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-image, sips

I want to scale images to 400x400 (I am creating thumbnails). I am using the Scriptable Image Processing System (SIPS) in a Cocoa application, but the problem is poor efficiency. SIPS takes 70-90% CPU while converting 300 images in 20 seconds. Should I use the `CIImage` class (`CIImage` is the type required to use the various GPU-optimized Core Image filters) or `NSImage` class? Can anyone suggest a better method?

Comment: You should try them both and see what's fastest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried thumbnail genration using NSImage , CIImage and sips. All are taking same CPU (70-90%) usage but sips is faster.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and fast way to generate thumbnails on OS X is to use [QLThumbnailImageCreate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/QLThumbnailRequest_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005055-CH3-SW4).
It's just one line of code so you can easily try out how it compares to SIPS & Core Image.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am using sips because it is efficient then  Core image and QLThumbnailImageCreate.